# Angular. How to wrap existing control value accessor inside my own control?

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I want to make a control that encapsulates the input tag and add some additional logic. Let's say autocomplete. I want my control to use DefaultValue accessor that already exists for `input` tag. So I've done a code:

```
export class AutocompleteComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

    @ViewChild(DefaultValueAccessor)
    inputValueAccessor: DefaultValueAccessor;

    writeValue(obj: any): void {
        this.inputValueAccessor.writeValue(obj);
    }
    registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
        this.inputValueAccessor.registerOnChange(fn);
    }
    registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
        this.inputValueAccessor.registerOnTouched(fn);
    }
    setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
        this.inputValueAccessor.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
    }

}
```

The problem is that `inputValueAccessor` will be initialized when AfterViewInit will happen and `inputValueAccessor` will be needed way before it. So far I can imaging only workaround to 'postpone' calls to `inputValueAccessor` till it will be initialized. is there a more elegant way to deal with it?

Comment: use into constructor

Comment: @Shohel may u please elaborate?

Comment: Share your code bro?